# Method that Searches 2-D array for a specific number and will return a Boolean value of true if found

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, methods, parameters

I am writing a program that creats a two-dimensional array fills it with random numbers and then prompts the user to enter a number and searches the 2-d array for that number.

I have the entire program completed beside the last method which I am lost on.
I am supposed to have this method return a bool to indicate if the sought out number was found or not.  I am supposed to initialize the row and column parameters to -1 and have this method to use first parameter and the 2-d array parameter to search the array for the number.  If the number is found I am to assign the row and column parameters to the row and column index where it is found and stop searching the array right away.

Any advice on the `searchArray()` method is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is the code filled with errors in the last method that I have so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int [,] randomNumArray = new int[3, 5];


        FillArray(randomNumArray);
        PrintArray(randomNumArray);
        SumRows(randomNumArray);
        SumCols(randomNumArray);
        SumArray(randomNumArray);
        GetNumber();

    }

    public static void FillArray(int[,] randomNumbersArray)
    {
        Random num = new Random();
        for (int r = 0; r < randomNumbersArray.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < randomNumbersArray.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                randomNumbersArray[r, c] = num.Next(15, 97);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void PrintArray(int[,] randomPrintArray)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < randomPrintArray.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < randomPrintArray.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0,3:F0}", randomPrintArray[r, c]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    public static void SumRows(int[,] sumOfRowsArray)
    {
        int rowSum;
        for (int r = 0; r < sumOfRowsArray.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            rowSum = 0;
            for (int c = 0; c < sumOfRowsArray.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                rowSum += sumOfRowsArray[r, c];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The total sum for row "+ (r + 1) + " is:  " + rowSum + ".");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    public static void SumCols(int[,] sumOfColsArray)
    {
        int colsSum;
        for (int c = 0; c < sumOfColsArray.GetLength(1); c++)
        {
            colsSum = 0;
            for (int r = 0; r < sumOfColsArray.GetLength(0); r++)
            {
                colsSum += sumOfColsArray[r, c];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The total sum for column " + (c + 1) + " is:  " + colsSum + ".");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    public static void SumArray(int[,] sumOfAllArray)
    {
        int sumOfAll = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < sumOfAllArray.GetLength(0); r++)
        {

            for (int c = 0; c < sumOfAllArray.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                sumOfAll += sumOfAllArray[r, c];
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Total for sum of the Array is:  "  + sumOfAll + "\n");
    }

    public static int GetNumber()
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter a number between 15 and 96:  ");
        int chosenNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (chosenNumber > 96 || chosenNumber < 15)
        {
            Console.Write("Number not between 15 and 96.  Try again:  ");
            chosenNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        return chosenNumber;
    }


    public static bool SearchArray(int soughtOutNum, int [,] searchableArray, out int rowIndex, out int colsIndex)
    {
        bool itsTrue == false;
        for (int c = 0; c < searchableArray.GetLength(0); c++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < searchableArray.GetLength(1); r++)
            {
                if (searchableArray[r, c] == soughtOutNum)
                {
                    return itsTrue == true;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Note that the `==` operaor is not equal to the `=` operator. `==` is used as a conditional operator (inside if statements) and `=` is used to assign values. So for example, when you declase `itsTrue`, you need to use `=` and not `==`, as follow : `bool itsTrue = false;`.

Comment: Alrite I changed that but it still wont run It says not all paths return a variable which I can see as the if statement returns one and not the outer for loop.  I feel like the structure of this method is all wrong for its purpose.

Comment: It says that because when you declare a method, it must return a value in all cases (unless its void). Because your `return` statement is inside an `if` statement, the compiler lets you know that there might be a case where nothing is returned from the method. i.e when `searchableArray[r, c] == soughtOutNum` will be false all the time. Then there will be an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has four problems that I can see.

First, two of your parameters are marked as `out` parameters, but you haven't filled in a value for them.  Think of out parameters like multiple return values: instead of the caller passing your function something, you're passing it back out.  Since the person calling this function is probably going to rely on the values in those, you have to explicitly give them a value.  This is probably giving you compiler errors.

I would start by assigning -1 to each of the two out parameters at the beginning of your function, and when you find the number you're searching for (that inner if statement), overwrite those -1's with the real answer (hint: how do you know what column and row you're on?)

Second, your use if `itsTrue` is a bit odd.  In C# (and many other languages), we use a single `=` for assignment, and a double `==` for comparison.  If you fix that, it should work, and give you the right answer.  However, from a code clarity standpoint, why do you need the variable at all?  It's never used except as a return value... why don't you just return `true` directly when you find the number you're looking for.

Third, your method isn't guaranteed to return a value: what happens if it never finds a number?  Eventually, you're going to fall outside of both for loops, and you'll reach that `Console.WriteLine("");` you have at the bottom... but what do you return in that case?

Finally, when you call the method, you need to let C# know where to stick the values of those out parameters.  Right now, when you try to call `SearchNumber(10)`, it can't find a method with just ONE parameter.  There's only one with 3.  You should instead declare variables where you can store the row and column, and then pass those in, like so:

```
int row, col;
SearchNumber(10, out row, out col);
```

Comment: Alrite I initialized both of the out parameters and looked them up.  but now I can't figure out how to loop it so it will always return a value. I am looking at it trying to figure out how to write it so it will just break out of it and print the result when it finds the number.  but if it doesn't find it, it needs to loop again till it does.  So what kind of loop would you suggest for this?

Comment: You code is almost right.  You just need one little change.  If you *naturally* fall out of the loop and reach the bottom, that means you didn't find the number right? So you need to let the person calling you know by returning false right there at he end.

Uwe provided a complete solution.  I was trying to help you understand why you need to make the changes, without giving you explicit code, because understanding is far more useful than just a copy-paste answer.  Hopefully my explanations were helpful!

Comment: I added another paragraph explaining the other issue you're having below.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not so far away from the solution if I understood you correctly. Are you looking for something like this?

```
    public static bool SearchArray(int soughtOutNum, int[,] searchableArray, out int rowIndex, out int colsIndex)
    {
        rowIndex = -1;
        colsIndex = -1;
        // Assuming your c is column and r is row
        for (int c = 0; c < searchableArray.GetLength(0); c++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < searchableArray.GetLength(1); r++)
            {
                if (searchableArray[r, c] == soughtOutNum)
                {
                    rowIndex = r;
                    colsIndex = c;
                    //Console.WriteLine("found number");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        //Console.WriteLine("Number not found");
        return false;
    }
```

**Update** to answer to the comment:
I coded it without a Visual Studio at hand so look out for typos.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int [,] randomNumArray = new int[3, 5];


    FillArray(randomNumArray);
    PrintArray(randomNumArray);
    SumRows(randomNumArray);
    SumCols(randomNumArray);
    SumArray(randomNumArray);
    int row;
    int column;
    int search = GetNumber();
    if (SearchArray(search, randomNumArray, out row, out column))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("found " + search + " at row " + row + " col " + column);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number not found");
    }

}
```

**Update 2:**
There is also an error in the last method.
You have constructed your array like this: randomNumbersArray[row, column]

In all methods *r* is from *GetLength(0)* and *c* is *GetLength(1)*. But in the last method you switch and your *r is GetLength(1)* and *c is GetLength(0)*. So you switch the numbers when accessing the array and essentially call randomNumbersArray[column, row]. This will give you an error when c_max != r_max.

Comment: alrite I coded that i am having troubles properly calling the method,  I need the chosen number to be passed to the `soughtOutNum` parameter am I correct?  right now I have `SearchArray(chosenNumber)` and it says it doesnt exist in the current context.  Do I have to initialize it in the main?

Comment: Yes. You would have to initialize the variable before passing it to the method. For testing you can call it hardcoded with a number you know exists in the array. For example if you know 10 is in the array call SearchArray(10, arraytosearch, out row, out column).

Comment: So im returning the varable chosenNumber from the `GetNumber()` method.  How do I get that to be passed into the parameter listing `int soughtOutNum` to be used in that method.      right now the method call I have set up is as follows:    `SearchArray(,randomNumArray, out rowIndex, out colsIndex);`          I believe it is just missing that chosen number variable and the rowIndex and colsIndex dont exist in that context. Am I on the right track?  I can't find out how to pass it down to that method to use.

Comment: when I run this code it prompts me to enter a number and if I enter anything within the condition of the while loop it runs fine but if I enter anything within the range of the array it then crashes with an error saying the index was outside the boundaries of the array.  So I know it gets to the method its just something else is wrong.

Comment: I believe there is another error in your code. See my Update2 of the answer.